# Unable to render CSS in MAMP localhost

Tags: css, apache, mamp

I am experiencing something very strange when implementing the [Metronic Admin panel](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/) into a new Laravel project. I have broken everything up into partial blade files, and included all CSS and JS using the standard

```
{{ asset('...') }}
```

blade syntax. The problem I am facing is the loading of a single CSS file, in that all browsers will hit this point and stop. What is even weirder is that there are no console errors and no output in the performance tab in Chrome, everything just hangs.

The CSS file in question is

```
<link href="{{ asset('admin/demo/demo3/base/style.bundle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Unminified, this CSS file is 55,000 lines long so I'm not too sure if this is something to do with just the sheer size of the file, however, leaving Chrome for 15 minutes has not produced any results at all.

I am able to open the static HTML file from the download folder, which links to this same file and renders perfectly fine, using the file:// method, but when these files are added into the localhost path, the same problem happens again. This leads me to believe this is not a problem with Laravel, but a problem with the localhost instance instead.

The localhost is running the latest version of MAMP on Windows 10, not had any other problems with any other sites, just this single CSS file.

I can also see in the Apache access.log file that these assets are being found with a 200 status code

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018:21:05:41 +0100] "GET /digitaltools/public/home HTTP/1.1" 200 623
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018:21:05:41 +0100] "GET /digitaltools/public/admin/vendors/base/vendors.bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 357894
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2018:21:05:41 +0100] "GET /digitaltools/public/admin/demo/demo3/base/style.bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1736133
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a clean install of MAMP this seems to have solved the problem. Very strange behaviour.